# Product select attribute whose value is textarea with wysiwyg

Tags: product-attribute

I have product select attribute for product material. Now I have created select attribute and in admin I can choose product material and it's ok. But in front I want to show material image and description.

**So I need that select option value  was textarea and i could put into them image and description.**

There is any way to have what I want?

Comment: So you mean if the drop down is selected in admin, then only a textarea should come on front?

Comment: Yes. For example, if admin choosed laminat, in front i should show image and description for laminat.

Comment: If you do not have many options then you can try creating multiple attribute sets? I am not sure but may be that can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best approach on this is to create your own CRUD module where you manage materials.
Each material should have a title, description and image. (and any other field you need).
Then you can make that entity you create into a product attribute.
[This shows you how to create a product attribute with a custom source model.](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html)

Then in the product page you can add a section where you can show the details of the material.
Something like this:

```
<?php $materialId = $_product->getMaterial();
if ($materialId) : 
    $material = Mage::getModel('[module]/material')->load($materialId); ?>
    <div class="material-description"><?php echo $material->getDescription();?></div>
    <div class="material-image"><img src="BASE IMAGE PATH HERE <?php echo $material->getImage()?>" /></div>
<?php endif;?>
```